# Conditional expression in Sympy

Tags: sympy

If I try to have an expression whose value depends on another expression

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
y1 = x/cos(x)
y2 = y2 if y1>0 else nan
```

but an exception is raised

```
File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py:511, in Relational.__bool__(self)
    510 def __bool__(self):
--> 511     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Is there a chance of having the effect that I'd want?

---

In case my problem is a X-Y problem, what I ultimately want to do is to plot `x/cos(x)` only where the function is positive.

---

UPDATE

I used the useful suggestion of @Oscar Benjamin (that completely answers my original question) but I have other issues when plotting the `Piecewiswe` function, that I'll expose in another question, as well as a wrong  plot when I use the `plot_implicit` solution they suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Piecewise`:

```
In [8]: p = Piecewise((x/cos(x), x/cos(x) > 0), (S.NaN, True))

In [9]: p
Out[9]: 
⎧  x           x       
⎪──────  for ────── > 0
⎨cos(x)      cos(x)    
⎪                      
⎩ nan      otherwise
```

A more direct solution to your problem though would be something like

```
plot_implicit(Eq(y, x/cos(x)) & (x/cos(x) > 0))
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it solves the X part of my problem. Alas, it doesn't solve the Y part... (also the `plot_implicit` part of your answer doesn't help). Sooner or later I will post another question focused  on Y :-)